# I can't get CodeIgniter posts with specific categories to show on home page (I will delete this if it turns out to be a duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, blogs

I am looking for suggestions, I searched the questions on here and did not find anything that matched what I was asking. That being said if you feel this is a duplicate I will gladly remove the question, and hopefully get the link to the OP.

I am new to CodeIgniter and I have built out the blog portion of a website (auth, post index, create posts and categories, and comments) on top of that I have the db setup to attach the category_id to each new post.

My issue is that I can list the categories and even link them to an index  filtered to just post with that category name but I am trying to list posts categorized as featured articles on the home page of the website So once you visit the website latest featured articles can be displayed with a read more.

Below is all the code for making the categories show in list form on the view/categories/index.php and views/posts/index.php. I thought I could use the get_posts_by_category to display outside of the categories index page but I get this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: categories

Filename: pages/home.php

**The Index portion of the Posts.php Controller**

```html
public function index($offset = 0){
   // Pagination Config
   $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'posts/index/';
   $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('posts');
   $config['per_page'] = 3;
   $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
   $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
   // Init Pagination
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $data['title'] = 'Latest Posts';
   $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts(FALSE, $config['per_page'], $offset);
   $this->load->view('templates/header');
   $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
```

**get_posts port of the Post_model.php**

```html
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE) {
          if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
       }
            if($slug === FALSE) {
              $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
              $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
                $query = $this->db->get('posts');
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
         return $query->row_array();
        }
```

**get_categories and get_posts_by_category portion of the Post_model.php**

```html
public function get_categories() {
          $this->db->order_by('name');
          $query = $this->db->get('categories');
          return $query->result_array();
        }
        public function get_posts_by_category($category_id) {
          $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
          $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');

            $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('category_id' => $category_id));

            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

** View portion of the categories/index.php**

```html
<h2><?= $title; ?></h2>
<ul class="list-group">
<?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>

 <li class="list-group-item">
  <a href="<?php echo site_url('/categories/posts/'.$category['id']); ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>

    <!-- user data -->
  <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $category['user_id']): ?>

   <form class="cat-delete" action="categories/delete/<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" method="POST">

    <input type="submit" class="btn-link text-danger" value="[X]">

   </form>
  <?php endif; ?>
 </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Categories Controller** - index an posts function

```html
  public function index(){
    $data['title'] = 'Categories';
    $data['categories'] = $this->category_model->get_categories();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('categories/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
public function posts($id){
    $data['title'] = $this->category_model->get_category($id)->name;
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts_by_category($id);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
```

**Below is of the MySQL db table for posts (figured I can call the category_id)**

id
category_id
title
slug
body
post_image
created_at

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: categories
>
> Filename: pages/home.php

Implies that your view (home.php) is attempting to use a variable (categories) that is not defined, i.e. not passed in by the controller.

You ARE correctly passing the variable to a view called "index", here:

```
$data['categories'] = $this->category_model->get_categories();
$this->load->view('categories/index', $data);
```

But not "home"... where are you loading "home"? Where ever that is, you would need to pass the data to it in the same fashion as above.